# When Delete the blob in azure cloud The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Tags: c#, azure, cloud, azure-storage

The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found ..How to  Solve this Problem...

```
    public object Delete(string name)
    {
        dynamic deleted = true;

        try
        {
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = SMBS.GetBlobContainer();
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container1");

            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
            blockBlob.Delete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            deleted = false;
        }

        return deleted;
    }
```

Comment: You aversion to `bool` is interesting. Why don't you use it?

Comment: I can't understand what u tell?

Comment: Why are you returning `object` and using `dynamic`, where in both cases you could use `bool`?

Comment: What is the value of `name` that you are using? Are you sure it's the blob name and not the blob's absolute url?

Comment: its a blob name. the value  is ("example.jpg ") just nw only try

Answer (score 4):

The blob could be actually missing or your request might not be authenticated. Please see if the credentials are correct. In addition, there is already a [ICloudBlob.DeleteIfExists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.icloudblob.deleteifexists.aspx) method in Azure Storage Client Library that you can use instead of your Delete method.

Comment: Its Working ...Thanks to Answering Me

Comment: how did you fix that? I'm having the same issue. Upload works fine using same credentials, delete gives me 404.

Comment: I'm observing 404 with DeleteIfExists() as well.  I suspect Azure design team intended this behavior, to return 404 status if the object did not exist in any cases; though, it would be nice if it did it silently without throwing an Exception.